# Javascript object / array question?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object-model

I am new to the javascript object model (prototype based) and am trying to do the following:

I have a constructor that simply initializes an array: `this.myArray = []`. I have a method:

```
MyConstructor.prototype.addToArray = function(myObject, type) {
   //
};
```

Basically I need `myArray` to be attached to a specific `type`.  I.e. when `addToArray()` is called, the object will be added to an array associated with the `type`.  I don't want to have to know all the possible types ahead of time.  I also will need to add methods that clear the array holding objects of a certain type.  So basically, I think I need to somehow create arrays dynamically which are associated with a type.

Any help would be appreciated.

I think my question is confusing so I'll try to elaborate: my "business" code creates objects which I need to keep track of. Each objects is associated with a certain "type" or "flavor". I am trying to make a generic object which handles storing these object references in arrays (an array per type) and handling operations on these objects.  Operations then could be performed on all objects of a given type.  I want to be able to do this without knowing the types ahead of time (i.e. avoid creating 1 array per type in the constructor).

"Type" could be anything. i.e. a string "typeA", or "typeB" etc. just a way of differentating between different classes of objects.

Comment: Your question is confusing. JavaScript is dynamically typed so there really aren't that many different things you'll get back from [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator). Are you basically talking about creating homogenous arrays, e.g. one array to store strings, another to store numbers, and so on?

Comment: Do your business objects have a property that identifies their "type"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like this:

```
var objects = {};
...
if (objects[type]) {
    objects[type].push(myObject);
} else {
    objects[type] = [myObject];
}
//...similar methods to delete objects, etc.
```

Comment: what does setting the variable equal to {} do? How is this different than setting it equal to [] ? thanks

Comment: {} is an empty object. I'm using it kind of like an associative array: it has an array [] of objects for each type, as object[type] = [obj1, obj2, ...]. This is also like: object = {type1: [obj1, ...], type2: [foo, bar, ...]}.

Comment: The {} part you want to leave outside your function; the rest goes inside to add the object to the corresponding array. Sorry I can't be more helpful, I'm typing this on my phone... :)

Comment: hmm..this sounds this would help me.  I guess when adding an object of a certain type for the first time I would need to check if object[type] is defined and then create it etc.

Comment: Exactly the solution I would have selected. +1

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I'm doing on the 5th & 6th lines.

Comment: Im getting a problem where if objects[type] is not defined, and it tries to do objects[type] = [myObject] I get a "cannot set property of .. undefined".  Im probably missing something small from making this work

Comment: Is it saying that "objects" is undefined or something else is?

Comment: sorry nevermind..my fault.  I typed something in wrong.  This works perfectly.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If I've interpreted your question correctly, it's not possible to do what you want as JavaScript arrays are not typed - You can put any type of object in any array.

**EDIT:**

In light of your update, it sounds like you could have an object that has properties that match your object constructor names. Each property contains an array that holds objects created with a constructor that matches the property name.

For example,

```
function Cache() {}

Cache.prototype.add = function (obj) {
this[obj.constructor.name] === undefined? this[obj.constructor.name] = [obj] :
this[obj.constructor.name].push(obj);
}

function Constructor1(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

var cache = new Cache;
var con1 = new Constructor1('me', 10);
cache.add(con1);

console.log(cache) // has property 'Constructor1' containing an array with reference
                   // to object con1 in.
```

With this approach, you'll need to be careful and augment the constructor name when inheriting from objects.